# HTML unable to target different devices

Tags: html, css

I built a site using HTML, CSS, and Javascript. It has two layouts I would like the site to choose automatically using the screen size. To do this, I linked to two CSS files in my index file. Here is how I formatted it.

```html
    
<link rel="stylesheet" media='screen and (min-width: 750px)' href="css/largeScreen.css">
    
<link rel="stylesheet" media='screen and (max-width: 750px)' href="css/smallScreen.css">
```

This works on my computer when I change the size of my browser window. However, when I uploaded my site online and accessed it with my phone, I realized that it doesn't pick the correct layout (should be from the smallScreen.css file).

If anyone can help me with this issue, it would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: You could try adding `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` to the head, this tells the browser to use the screen width of the device which can vary depending on pixel density

Comment: @ThomasAltmann, didn't see your comment at first.  If this is the case, you should post and answer and get best answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @ThomasAltmann said, have you set

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

in your `<head>`?  I came accross this issue that had me stumped for hours before realizing I forgot this tag.  This tells mobile browsers not to automatically scale the website to display it as if it were on a normal desktop-sized window.